# Matlab take 1 string at a time

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function such that the input will be string but the output will be pause version of every string like, say example is do the job and the input will be "Matlab". Then, the output will be displayed at the command window as:

```
fprintf('M')
pause(0.001)
fprintf('A')
pause(0.001)
fprintf('T')
pause(0.001)
fprintf('L')
pause(0.001)
fprintf('A')
pause(0.001)
fprintf('B')
```

I can do the above code for short term. But, there are huge difficulties to apply this idea for every dialogue. Just say it 100 sentences. How can i read each letter and display it accordingly?

Comment: Use a loop maybe? In pseudocode: `for` every `letter` in your `sentences`: `disp(letter); pause(0.01);`

Comment: I'm confused.  So you have a bunch of sentences... do you want to display each **sentence** with a pause, or each letter within a sentence with a pause.... or each word with a pause?

Comment: I just recognized what confused you. I meant as the output of the code, every letter - not every word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to display all the letters in a sentence with a delay:

```
% --- Definition
s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog';

% --- Display loop
for i = 1:numel(s)
    fprintf(s(i));
    pause(0.01);
end
fprintf('\n');
```

---

Here is a solution to display all the words in a sentence with a delay. I use `textscan` to isolate the words.

```
% --- Definition
s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog';

% --- Get words
tmp = textscan(s, '%s');
w = tmp{1};

% --- Display loop
for i = 1:numel(w)
    fprintf('%s ', w{i});
    pause(0.1);
end
fprintf('\n');
```

works nicely, with a cool retro effect.

Comment: I think I am going to use your code every time i display anything